# How to merge multiple RSS feeds into one, in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, rss, feed

I have a bunch of RSS feeds in Firefox. If you've ever subscribed to one, you'll know it creates what looks like a folder, which upon hovering, pops out to show the contents of the feed.

I want to have it so that I simply have one "folder" on my bookmarks tool-bar, which, which expanded, shows them all in one - as in, if I had 3 feeds I was subscribed to when I click on the folder it will show:

```
[]
[] Name of content on site 1
[] Name of content on site 2
[] Name on content of site 2
[] Name of content on site 3                  *in chronological order*
[] Name of content on site 4
[] Name of content on site 1
```

Is this possible? I guess the only way it could work is if RSS feeds have timestamps, do they? I've practically no knowledge of how they work.

If it does turn out to be impossible in firefox, what's the lowest footprint software that can accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just use [FEEDcombine](http://www.feedcombine.co.uk/st/content/makefeed/), you enter in all of the desired feeds, then it gathers them for you and gives you a combined feed link you can bookmark.

[Here's](http://www.feedcombine.co.uk/feed.php?id=534bb93a5223a6e24f2223c76f7d0e19#) an example of StackOverflow and SuperUser feeds combined:

[image]

Comment: "The script is hosted on a server that is shared by a number of sites and we're no longer able to offer this service as a result of the actions of few abusive users."

Answer (score 1):

I use [Sage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/77) to read RSS, and while it doesn't offer the functionality you want, you might be interested in filing a feature request to do so. You probably won't get this behaviour in plain firefox, but in an add-on like Sage you might have a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to FEEDcombine is [RSSMix](http://www.rssmix.com/), which I've used in the past, and can vouch for. You just give it a list of RSS feeds and it spits out a URL to a combined feed. Very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader) for this. I get to see all of my feeds combined in one chronological list, either newest first or oldest first.

Not native to Firefox, and you would have to go to another site, but it *does* get the job done of a combined feed. It also has the benefit of being able to see them individually too, or in arbitrary groups, as well as search the history of every subscribed RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

I would add  [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to the List of Programs - a page where you can add, combine, filter different RRS Feeds and put it on a Page in a single Feed. if you are not sure how to do so you can serarch for pipes of other Users - and often you can copy an existing pipe for the Feeds you want to have.